# fetch data from multiple tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [fetch multiple tables in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825736/fetch-multiple-tables-in-one-query)

I want fetch data from 3 tables, like this:

```
$query = select * from categories,settings,articles
```

I have 3 records in articles table, 4 records in categories table, and 2 records in the settings table.

I want fetch all data in the articles table.

If I used

```
while($test = mysql_fetch_array($query){
    echo $test[post_title];
}
```

It repeats 9 times, the total of three tables' records, which I understand to be the correct output for this query.

Can I fetch only posts without others? or should each be queried alone?