# fetch multiple tables in one query

Tags: php

This is thirty post in one houre . so i am sorry !

but i did't get what i want !

i will try to explain more ..

i have two tables ..

POSTS <-- my ( all site posts )
COMMENTS <-- my ( all site comments )

i want display all POSTS and COMMENTS in this one page

buy ( 1 query )

i have in POSTS table (100 post)
and i have in COMMENTS table ( 20 comment )

i try this code

```
$qq = mysql_query("SELECT posts.*,comments.* 
FROM posts LEFT JOIN comments 
ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id");
    while($tt = mysql_fetch_array($qq)){
    echo $tt['comment_title'] . '<br />'; //the title of comments !
}
```

in above , iam trying to print comment title

i said above i have ( 20 comments ) only !

the code is output ( 120 comments with repeat ! )

120 is the total of the two tables !

/* i want only print the 20 comments and the 100 post ( in one query )

How i can do that ! ?

in the end i am sorry for this more question

but i am really need help ! my site is down

Comment: You have "categories", "settings" and "articles", what are "posts"?

Comment: Articles table <- its contain my posts

Comment: Please do not repost same question. You can edit your previous question. If you have further queries regarding the same question.

Comment: So your site did already work?

Comment: It's not possible to have tow different schema for one query response. and what you want, is that! what is your problem to use more than one query?

Comment: Hello guys 
<Starx> i am so sorry it will never repeat 
<home> Yup it was working fine with more than one querys ( i was have 6 querys and decided to convert it to one query
<saeed> the script require more querys and thank you for your idea
<sander> thank you i will try multiple querys
thank you guys and sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is super ambiguous, so I will do my best:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id
```

That is the query you want (same that you have, but * instead of "posts.*,comments.*".

This will, of course, retrieve all the rows in Posts, even if they don't have any comments.  You need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id WHERE posts.post_id= = <some_id>
```

to get only a specific post's comments.  Of course, that would be silly since it would be the same thing as just doing:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id = <some_id>
```

If you want to only select rows in Posts that have comments, you must do:

```
SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN comments ON posts.post_id = comments.post_id
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM posts NATURAL JOIN comments
```

(they have the same effect)

Comment: anyway i should make two querys !
i was working fine with two querys but i decided to short them in one query ! but it seems a bad idea ,  Thank you chris very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to get all posts (and by posts you mean articles)

yes, you can use one query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles;
```

To get all articles

Comment: yes i know !,
but also i want get all categories and all settings !
i want use one query to fetch the all three tables !

Comment: without more info about the fields on your tables, I would suggest you head to mysql's documentation on JOINs here -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html hope it can be of help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query){
    echo $result['post_title'];
}
?>
```